# table not refreshing after deleting a row in primefaces p:datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

So I hava table which has 4 columns.The 4th columns has a button which deletes the record,when the button is cliked a modal dialog opens up and then it asks for confirmation Yes (or) NO.So when I click on Yes the record gets deleted from the database and also the modal dilog closes but the table is not getting refreshed.If I manually refresh it the record does not show.

This is my code in JSF for the modal dialog:

```
<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Delete User?"  modal="true"
resizable="false" draggable="false" widgetVar="delUserConf">  
  <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2">
   <h:outputLabel value="Name" style="font-weight: bold"/>
   <h:outputText value="#{userController.selectedBean.firstName}" style="border: none"/>
 </h:panelGrid>
 <p:commandButton oncomplete='delUserConf.hide();' actionListener="#{mybeanr.deleteUser(userController.selectedBean)}"  id="yesDeleteUser" value="#{bundle.ListUserDeleteYes}" update=":userForm"/>
 <p:commandButton id="noDelete" onclick="delUserConf.hide();" action="/views/user/UserManagement.xhtml" value="#{bundle.ListUserDeleteNo}" style="margin-left: 15px;" update=":userForm:dataTab"/>
</p:dialog>
```

where 'userForm' is the if of the form. The dialog button is not in the p:datatable.My code in the bean:

```
public String deleteUser(UserBean userbean) {
 //do something
 selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();

 if(//condiition checking )
 {
     JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Not Allowed");
 }
 else
 {
   try {
       //some logic here
       JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Success");
   } catch (Exception e) {
       JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Error");
   }
   //performDestroy();
   recreatePagination();
   recreateModel();
 }
 return "UserDetails";
}
```

Datatable and form code:

```
<h:form id="userForm">
 <p:growl id="growl"  showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
  <div class="dataTableWrap">
   <p:dataTable value="#{mybean.usersList}" var="item" id="dataTab" widgetVar="usersTable" editable="true" rowKey="#{item.emailAddress}">
   have some columns here and just displaying the values of these columns from the beans.
  </p:datatable>
</h:form>
```

UserDetails is the jsf page where I have this table.If you notice I am returning few messages from the bean.This is working fine but I do not understand why the table is not getting refreshed.Could anyone let me know why?

Comment: Can you post form and datatable code ? And have you check if you have javascript error ?

Comment: added the datatable and the form code in the question...

Comment: There are no script errors also..

Comment: You dont close your div ?

Comment: Sorry that was just an copy paste error it looks fine in my form. I have the div tag closed.

Comment: @Lamq any idea about what I am missing here

Comment: Make sure your dialog is inside a form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you updating the mybean.usersList? I don't know what recreatePagination() and recreateModel() do, but, since you are not using lazy model, try to remove the deleted userbean from the list after you perform destroy. Something like

```
public String deleteUser(UserBean userbean) {
 //do something
 selectedItemIndex = pagination.getPageFirstItem() + getItems().getRowIndex();

 if(//condiition checking )
 {
     JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Not Allowed");
 }
 else
 {
   try {
       //some logic here
       JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Success");
   } catch (Exception e) {
       JsfUtil.addErrorMessage("Error");
   }
   //performDestroy();

   usersList.remove(userBean);

   recreatePagination();
   recreateModel();
 }
 return "UserDetails";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when deleting from an entity from the jsf uifront end,the entity is not in a managed state,
so u need to merge back to obtain the managed object, and now delete using the    emcreateQuery("") to delete where entity object exists on table, or u can do geList().remove(entity) from jsf ui . The first options deletes from the db instantly refreshing the page and the second option deletes the merged entity and also removes it from the ui list